# Legend (base graphics) not getting drawn

Tags: r, plot, legend

I'm new to R so forgive me if the problem is obvious.

The problem I've got is that my legend just wont get shown 
and there're no errors telling me something is wrong. I've been checking
the documentations for legends and I can't see where I've gone wrong.

The legend code looks like this:

```
legend(1, g_range[2], c("Client0","Client1"), cex=0.8, 
   col=c("blue","red"), pch=21:22, lty=1:2);
```

A note, everything in my graph works, just that the legend isn't drawn!

How is the drawingorder in R? What happens if one of the plots / lines crosses the space where the legend is supposed to be?

Will the line/plot be seen through the legend, will the legend overlap the lines/plot, will the plot/lines "hide" the legend?

Here is the whole code:

```
 #Define the two Clients and their Deficencies
Client0 <- c(0,3.14,3.60,3.41,3.7,3.6,3.6)
Client1 <- c(0,1.26,1.7,4,2.82,3.42,4)

# Calculate range from 0 to max value of cars and trucks
g_range <- range(0, Client0, Client1)

# Graph autos using y axis that ranges from 0 to max 
# value in cars or trucks vector.  Turn off axes and 
# annotations (axis labels) so we can specify them ourself
plot(Client0, type="o", col="blue", ylim=g_range, 
   axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE)

# Make x axis using Mon-Fri labels
axis(1, at=1:7, lab=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7"))

# Make y axis with horizontal labels that display ticks at 
# every 1 marks. 1*0:g_range[2] is equivalent to c(0,1,2,3).
axis(2, las=1, at=1*0:g_range[2])

# Create box around plot
box()

# Graph trucks with red dashed line and square points
lines(Client1, type="o", pch=22, lty=2, col="red")

# Create a title with a red, bold/italic font
title(main="Deficiencies", col.main="red", font.main=4)

# Label the x and y axes with dark green text
title(xlab="Time", col.lab=rgb(0,0.5,0))
title(ylab="Deficiencies", col.lab=rgb(0,0.5,0))

# Create a legend at (1, g_range[2]) that is slightly smaller 
# (cex) and uses the same line colors and points used by 
# the actual plots 
legend(1, g_range[2]-1, c("Client0","Client1"), cex=0.8, 
   col=c("blue","red"), pch=21:22, lty=1:2);
```

Comment: legend is being shown at coordinates(1,g_range[2]-1)

Comment: Yeah just noticed. But still don't get why I had to press enter 1 extra time. Well new to R so I'm prob just stupid. Thanks for reply though

Comment: As far as I can see there is nothing wrong with the legend. If you still have problems, please edit your question accordingly. Otherwise, maybe deleting this question would make sense?